# Issues with service layers and domain models

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm developing an application with a service layer that operates on a domain model.  In the current design I'm passing domain objects up through the service layer (e.g. returning an `Employee` domain object when calling `EmploymentService.getEmployee()` , but require that operations performed on the objects go though the service (e.g. `EmploymentService.transferEmployee( int employeeId, int newLocationId)`.  (Examples are contrived, by the way).

This feels a little wrong to me.  One, it seems like procedural programming.  Two, the domain objects have setters like `Employee.setLocationId` that a client could invoke that of course wouldn't transfer the employee to a new location, as all of the complicated operations to coordinate different systems needed to hypothetically transfer the employee are in the service layer.

I'd feel better about this if I could hide the setters from the client, but both the ServiceLayer and DAOs in different packages need to be able to access the setters of domain objects.

Is this sort of thing ok, or is there a better way? (Also, any real-world examples of service layers with underlying domain models would be welcome!)

Also, I've read the Anemic Domain Model anti-pattern and I don't *think* I'm falling into that trap, but I'm not completely sure!

Comment: I'm not sure it solves the problem entirely, but wouldn't it make more sense to pass business objects, not primitives, when possible? For example: `EmploymentService.transferEmployee(Employee emp, Location newLoc)` Either way, +1 for caring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the problem of a client calling Employee.Transfer() which you don't actually want:
I like to return only DTO's from my Service Layer. These DTO's contain data and no methods. This solves the problem of a Client calling Employee.Transfer().

Next, the problem of having all code in EmploymentService.transferEmployee(). You say it doesn't feel right because it looks like procedural programming. The solution is to find a good mix between the logic you put into the Service and the logic you put into the Domain object. For example:

Domain object does:

- Check to see if it's not deleted
- Check to see if it's not already in that location
- etcetera

Service layers does:

- Load Employee
- Call Employee.Transfer
- Send email to employee
- Send email to location manager
- etcetera

I would probably use a Location Domain object in this code:

```
public class Location
{
   public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
   {
      if(!IsFull)
         Employees.Add(emp);
   }

   public void RemoveEmployee(Employee emp)
   {
      Employees.Remove(emp);
      If(Employees.Count < 100)
         IsFull = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if you choose to expose method-less DTOs at the service level, then for the code above I assume at the service layer you'd have something like `LocationService.AddEmployee( Location l, Employee e)`?  Also, do you include setters on your DTOs to facilitate updates (in conjunction with an Update call to a service layer class, I assume)?

Comment: I would do this: LocationService.AddEmployee( Guid locationId, Guid employeeId) or this: LocationService.AddEmployee( LocationDto l, EmployeeDto e). I prefer the ones with only ID's, the rest is overkill. You can also do this: TransferEmployeeService.Execute(Guid locationId, Guid employeeId)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, although you stated that your example was contrived, I want to say that `EmploymentService.transferEmployee(int employeeId, int newLocationId)` is kind of strange.  Usually you would transfer an `Employee` to a `Location`.  It's unusual to have to deal with ids in your Java code.   Most ORMs will handle that for you.

As for your question, I would put the logic for transferring an `Employee` in the `Employee` itself.  That way there's no chance that someone will call `Employee.setLocation(Location)` without the proper changes taking place.  That's much better than jumping through hoops trying to hide setters from certain Objects.

As stated in the Wikipedia page for [Anemic Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model), the pattern describes a system where Domain transformations are controlled by separate objects.  I personally think that transferring an `Employee` is indeed a transformation, and that the logic for such a transformation could and should be in the Domain layer.  Of course, these issues are always somewhat matters of taste, so you may think differently.

I found Martin Fowler's [original article on the issue](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) to be a very good argument for making your Domain objects capable of transforming themselves.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  What about aspects of transferring an Employee that involve interacting with entities that aren't really part of the domain, e.g. sending an email to an administrator when the employee is transferred?  That seems more appropriate for the service level and it's wrapping that sort of non-domain functionality neatly around the domain objects that's giving me fits.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you about sending emails needing to be in a service.  If you want to make sure that the email gets sent _every time_ an `Employee` is updated, I might fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` on update and have `Employee` register with an email service listener when `findEmployee` is called.  If, however, you only sometimes want an email sent, have a service that can send emails.  Then you can call `Service.sendEmail` after you call `Employee.setLocation`.

Comment: Actually, I meant, have an email object register as a listener with each `Employee` not the other way around.

Comment: I personally prefer to have my domain objects as little more than wrappers around the underlying records, and keeping the domain logic somewhere else in a central location rather than spread throughout the domain objects. That way when the domain logic changes, as it inevitably does, it's fairly localized. But as you say it's a matter of taste, and there's nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach to hide the setters from your client is to encapsulate all the getters that the client needs in an `IEmployee` interface, and code the service APIs to that interface. That way the setters are hidden from the clients, but still there for the services and DAOs that need them.

Comment: Good suggestions, I like it.  Thanks.